# SimpleXMLElement creating two XML Tags

Tags: php, xml

I'm building `xml` with the `SimpleXMLElement` Object from PHP.

While doing so I encountered the following problem, which i can't solve:

I'm generating the root `xml` element like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
```

But i get a 2 `XML` headers when i do `echo $xml->asXML();` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"></xml>
```

Which is obvioulsy wrong. But how can i fix this so i only get the

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
```

part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also supply the surrounding tag.

For example:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <BASETAG />');
```